# How to handle deletion during pagination?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say that we have an app where users can post messages on a public board.

I want to retrieve all the posts using pagination. It seems simple at first sight (and maybe it is?) ordering by the auto generated key and limiting to N posts/page. When the users reaches the bottom of the table view, the next posts would be retrieved starting at the last key from the previous fetch.

The problem is when a user decides to delete `post_x`. What if immediately after the deletion of that post, another user posts a message and that message is associated with the key that was associated with `post_x` before its deletion? This means that we will retrieve a newer post in the next page.

What would the solution to this problem be?

I thought about adding a time stamp child to the messages and ordering by that instead?

Or are transactions the way to go?

Thanks.

Comment: How would it be associated with the key? you mean the same key `post_x`?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, the auto generated keys by Firebase seem to be based on a time stamp, thus adding a new node would more than certainly not get the deleted node's key. So everything should work fine only with the keys provided by Firebase.